# Android Layout nullpointerException

Tags: android, android-layout, nullpointerexception

I am having a very weird exception!. First I reference to a Relative layout, then i try to get its visibility state, but the activity crashes and throws a **NullPointerException** at **getVisibilty()**;
I Have no idea why!, I spent a lot of time trying to figure out the problem but I couldn't!,Here is my Activity code:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main3d_activity);
    RelativeLayout optionLayout;
    optionLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_optionLayout);
    int vis= optionLayout.getVisibility();
```

main3d_activity code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include_headerbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        layout="@layout/headerbar_layout" />
    <include
        android:id="@+id/include_footerbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        layout="@layout/footerbar_layout" />

    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/vf"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/include_footerbar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/include_headerbar" >

        <include
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/container_mainlayout" />

        <include
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/living_layout" />

        <include
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/bedroom_layout" />

        <include
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/childrenbedroom_layout" />

        <include
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/kitchen_layout" />

        <include
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/dinningroom_layout" />

        <include
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/corridor_layout" />

        <include
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/roof_layout" />

        <include
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/garden_layout" />

        <include
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/garage_layout" />

        <include
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/container_mainlayout" />
    </ViewFlipper>

    <include
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/include_footerbar"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/include_headerbar"
        layout="@layout/slidingdrawer_infolayout" />

    <include
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        layout="@layout/slidingdrawer_roomslistlayout" />

    <include
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/include_footerbar"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        layout="@layout/logger_layout" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include_relativeMenu"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/include_headerbar"
        layout="@layout/options_menulayout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

options_menuLayout xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_optionLayout"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:background="@drawable/main_headerbackground"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:visibility="invisible" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/relativeMenuAllSensorsButton"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/main_headerbackground"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="Activation List"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/relativeMenuUsersButton"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeMenuAllSensorsButton"
    android:background="@drawable/main_headerbackground"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="Users"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/relativeMenuPreferencesButton"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeMenuUsersButton"
    android:background="@drawable/main_headerbackground"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="Settings"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

I tried cleaning the project, rebuilding the workspace and even using different emulator but the same problem persists!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `main3d_activity.xml` you have:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/include_relativeMenu"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_below="@+id/include_headerbar"
    layout="@layout/options_menulayout" />
```

And then in `options_menulayout.xml` you have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_optionLayout"
```

So it looks like you're overriding the id when you include it.  Remove

```
    android:id="@+id/include_relativeMenu"
```

from the include, or search for that ID rather than the other one.

Answer (score 3):

If you are calling a view that is located in another .xml file than the one that you set in etContentView you will Unfortunately get a null value that is returned by **findViewById()**. That's your case:

**main3d_activity.xml**, which does not contain **R.id.main_optionLayout**

You have to use LayoutInflator

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/include_relativeMenu"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/include_headerbar"
    layout="@layout/options_menulayout" />
```

Edit:

I noticed that you are calling options_menulayout using include tag but with

```
android:id="@+id/include_relativeMenu"
```

you have override the id of *options_menulayout* to *include_relativeMenu*

you have two choices:

1) delete the new id assigned to the included layout

```
android:id="@+id/include_relativeMenu"
```

so your xml become:

```
<include
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/include_headerbar"
    layout="@layout/options_menulayout" />
```

2) get reference to the new assigned id by calling

> optionLayout = (RelativeLayout)
>   findViewById(R.id.include_relativeMenu);

Answer (score 0):

You setContentView to main3d_activity, which does not contain `R.id.main_optionLayout` which isn't a problem until you try to access its visibility in the next method. It's null because that view (main_optionLayout) is never inflated.

Edit~ I see this code, in your main3d_activity layout:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/include_relativeMenu"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/include_headerbar"
    layout="@layout/options_menulayout" />
```

And to be honest, I am not familiar enough with include in XML to really say whether it's an issue to do this or not, but I still imagine you get the nullpointer because the relative layout you are trying to access is never directly inflated.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, I've done the same steps for logger_layout and it works like charm! the options_menuLayout is supposed to be inflated and so on the main_optionLayout. When I try to set the options_menuLayout visibility from the xml to true, it appears and its button children too. They even respond to their click listeners!

Comment: Well, the two things I would try would be making sure the 
android:visibility="invisible" is removed from the main_option layout to see if that changes it; second, try moving the layout to the main XML file temporarily and see if the Java responds differently. Good luck!